# One-point sets are G$_\delta$ in first-countable $T_1$ spaces

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, separation-axioms, first-countable

Can someone please verify my proof or offer suggestions for improvement? I am aware that there is a similar question elsewhere. I only need help with my proof in particular.

> Show that in a first-countable $T_1$ space, every one-point set is a $G_\delta$ set.

Let $X$ be a first-countable $T_1$ space. Let $x \in X$. Then, there exists a countable basis $\{B_n\}$ at $x$. Pick $y \neq x$. Since $X$ is $T_1$, $X -\{y\}$ is a neighborhood of $x$. So, there exists a $B_n$ such that $B_n \subseteq X - \{y\}$. But then, $y \notin B_n$. So, $y \notin \displaystyle{\bigcap_{i = 1}^\infty B_i}$. Clearly, $x \in \displaystyle{\bigcap_{i = 1}^\infty B_i}$. So, $\displaystyle{\bigcap_{i = 1}^\infty B_i} = \{x\}$.

Comment: what is $G_\delta$ set ?

Comment: @sha A $G_\delta$ set is a countable intersection of open sets. The terminology here comes from the German. The “G” stands for “Gebiet,” which means “open set,” and the “δ” for “Durchschnitt,” which means “intersection.”

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is correct. I think that my first sentence is full answer to your question, however validation says it must be at least 30 characters long, so I'm writing this. :-)

Answer (score 0):

A more complete proof may be like this.

A first countable space $X$ has a countable local basis at every point. Let $x \in X$ and let $\mathcal{B}_x = \{B_n : n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ denote the set of local basis at $x$. Pick $y \neq x$. Since, $X$ is $T_1$, the set  $X \setminus \{y\}$ is a neighborhood of $x$. Again, by property of local basis, there exists a $B_n$ such that $B_n \subseteq X \setminus \{y\}$. Call this $B_n$ to be $B_{n_{(y)}}$; therefore, $y \notin B_n$ and hence, $y \notin B_{n_{(y)}}$. Since, for every $y$, $y \notin B_{n_{(y)}}$, but $x \in B_{n_{y}}$ we must have $x \in \underset{y \ne x}{\bigcap} B_{n_{(y)}}$. Let's assume for the sake of contradiction that $\exists \  z $ such that $z \in \underset{y \ne x}{\bigcap} B_{n_{(y)}}$, then the only possible choice for $z$ is $x$ since the intersection is overall $y\ne x$. Thus, $\underset{y}{\bigcap} B_{n_{(y)}} = \{x\}$ and $\{x\}$ is $G_{\delta}$ as required.